# How to query all people using GraphQL with Star War API?

Tags: graphql

I tried the sample in the book Learning GraphQL, 1st Ed, by O'Reilly:

```
query {
 person(personID: 5) {
   name
   birthYear
 }
}
```

on https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql or https://studio.apollographql.com/public/star-wars-swapi/variant/current/explorer
and was able to get back:

```json
{
 "data": {
   "person": {
     "name": "Leia Organa",
     "birthYear": "19BBY"
   }
 }
}
```

However, I tried to look for how to omit the personID and get all people, but can't:

```
query {
 person {
   name
   birthYear
 }
}
```

or

```
query {
 allPeople {
   name
   birthYear
 }
}
```

They both gave errors and I can't find the answer in many parts of the book.

I did see an example like this in the book:

```
query {
  allLifts {
    name
    status 
  }
}
```

which is for all ski lifts in a "fake ski resort". So my Star War query is very similar to it but it doesn't work.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linked GraphiQL application, click on the book icon "Show Documentation Explorer" at the top left, then where it says "Root Types" click on "query: Root", and find the `allPeople` query.  This will find you the definition of that top-level query:

```
allPeople(
  after: String
  first: Int
  before: String
  last: Int
): PeopleConnection
```

So `allPeople` doesn't return a single `Person`, or a list of `[Person]`; instead, it uses a convention called a *connection* that enables pagination.  This originated with a browser GraphQL client library called Relay, and detailed information on the [connection pattern](https://relay.dev/docs/guides/graphql-server-specification/#connections) is available on Relay's Web site.

In GraphiQL, you can click on `PeopleConnection` to find out what fields that type has.  In this particular case it directly has `people` embedded in it so you can query for that

```
{
  allPeople {
    people { name, birthYear }
  }
}
```

But in the more general case, a connection has *edges*, and each edge has a *cursor* and a *node*, where the node is the actual value you're querying.  A typical generic connection-based query might look like

```
query FivePeople($after: String) {
  allPeople(after: $after, first: 5) {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        birthYear
      }
    }
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      endCursor
    }
  }
}
```

This will return five people at a time, as the query name and the `first:` field suggest.  If `hasNextPage` is true, then you can pass `endCursor` as the `after` variable to get the next five people.

Comment: so I guess there is no definite rule as to how to pull 1 vs pull all, such as `query {
  allLifts {
    name
    status 
  }
}`. It is not `query {
  allLifts { lifts {
    name
    status 
  } }
}` (not the same pattern as people above)

Comment: The `fieldReturningAConnection { edges { node { ... } } }` will be common across anything that uses the Relay connection pattern.  Also note that an API isn't required to use that pattern, and it's certainly possible to have a query field `people: [Person!]` that just returns the data as a list and your original query would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't omit any parameter, instead construct the correct query for your purpose.
I believe following is the query you meant to run

```
{
  allPeople {
    people {
      name
      birthYear
    }
  }
}
```